# Is this proof of path-connected $\implies$ connected correct?

Tags: general-topology, connectedness, path-connected

Let $U$, $V$ be two open disjoint sets over $X$ such that $X=U\cup V$. Let $p\in U$. For any $q\in V$, let $\alpha :[0,1]\rightarrow X$ be a path connecting $p$ and $q$. Then the set $A:=\alpha^{-1}(U)$ is open in $[0,1]$. Let $x:=\sup A$. Then $y=\alpha (x)\in \partial U$:

- If $W$ is an open set with $\alpha(x)\in W$, then $\alpha^{-1}(W)\cap A\neq \emptyset \implies \alpha(\alpha^{-1}(W)\cap A)=W\cap \alpha(A)=W\cap U\neq \emptyset$.
- Likewise, $\alpha^{-1}(W)\cap ([0,1]-A)\neq \emptyset\implies \alpha(\alpha^{-1}(W)\cap ([0,1]-A))=W\cap (\alpha([0,1])-U)\subset W\cap V\neq \emptyset$.

Now, if $\alpha(x)\in V$, then $U\cap V=\emptyset \implies \alpha(x)\notin \partial U$ (which is a contradiction). Then $\alpha(x)\in U$.
    For every $y\in \partial U$, we can find a path (through path concatenation) such that $\alpha (x)=y$ for some $x\in [0,1]$, so $y\in U \implies U=\overline U$. That is, $U$ is open and closed in $X$. Then $\alpha^{-1}(U)$ must be open and closed in $[0,1]\implies \alpha^{-1}(U)=[0,1]$ (because $[0,1]$ is connected). Thus $q\in U$ for every $q\in V$, which is a contradiction, and $V$ must be empty. Therefore, $X$ is connected.

Comment: what does $\alpha^{-1}\cap A$ mean?

Comment: sorry, wrong typesetting. Already corrected.

Comment: What exact definition of "connected" are you using? Once you have that $\partial U$ is not empty (because it contains $y$), you're pretty much done.

Comment: I'm using this: $X$ is connected iff $X=U\cap V$ (with $U$, $V$ disjoint and open) $\implies$ $U=\emptyset$ or $V=\emptyset$.

Comment: I think your argument is a very complicated way of saying that if $U$ and $V$ are open an disjoint then $\alpha^{-1}(U)$ and $\alpha^{-1}(V)$ are open and disjoint, and since they are a cover of $[0,1]$ it contradicts the connectedness of $[0,1]$.

Comment: Right, so which of $U$ or $V$ does $y$ lie in? In either case, it makes that set not open, a contradiction.

Comment: This really deserves to be split into two parts: First prove from first principles that $[0,1]$ is connected. Then, by the argument in your first two or three lines, any path-connected space must be connected because otherwise $\alpha^{-1}(U)$ and $\alpha^{-1}(V)$ would partition $[0,1]$ into disjoint open sets.

Comment: Put another way: $U$ is clopen, so its boundary must be empty.

Answer (score 1):

You know that $[0,1]$ is connected, so the image of $\alpha$ is connected. On the other hand,
$$
\alpha([0,1])=\bigl(\alpha([0,1])\cap U\bigr)\cup\bigl(\alpha([0,1])\cap V\bigr)
$$
is written as the disjoint union of two relative open sets. Connectedness forces either $\alpha([0,1])\cap U=\emptyset$ or $\alpha([0,1])\cap V=\emptyset$. This is a contradiction, because $\alpha(0)=p\in U$ and $\alpha(1)=q\in V$.